# Will a Mana Flower auto-consume Restoration Potions?

Tags: terraria

I was reading about some of the items that can be crafted with a Tinkerer's Workshop and saw that a [Mana Flower](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mana_Flower) will enable "auto-consumption of any mana-restoring items." Will this cause [Restoration Potions](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Restoration_Potion) to be consumed also? If so, it seems like a way to restore HP while avoiding the limitation of [Potion Sickness](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Potion_Sickness).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Mana Flower *will* select restoration potions to refill mana... but only if you don't have the potion sickness debuff in the first place.

This means it will not let you bypass the cooldown on health restoration items.